# How to get the Uri of the video captured with registerForActivityResult() in android?

Tags: android, uri, video-capture, registerforactivityresult, activityresultcontracts

I am trying to capture a video through the camera in my application, I am using registerForActivityResult() because startActivityForResult() has been deprecated. I am passing the ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo() as a contract in the registerForActivityResult(), but in the lambda function, the 'it' value that is present is a nullable Boolean, unlike ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview(), which has a nullable Bitmap as the 'it' value. The boolean only tells whether the video was successfully saved or not. Please can anyone tell me how to get the Uri of that recorded video?

I am using this code to take and save an image:-

```
val clickImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) {
    doAnythingWithThisImage(it)  // here, 'it' is a nullable Bitmap -> Bitmap?
}
clickImagelauncher.launch(null)
```

I want to do something similar for taking a video:-

```
val recordVideoLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo()) {
    if (it) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Video Saved!")  // here, 'it' is a nullable Boolean -> Boolean?
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error in saving video!")
    }
}
recordVideoLauncher.launch(Uri.EMPTY)  // -> Line A
```

It has something to do with the Uri passed in Line A. The documentation shows that Uri.EMPTY equates to "". The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo?hl=en) of the ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo() says that the recorded video is  saved in the provided content Uri. I recently came across 'Uri' class and have very less knowledge about it.
[Screenshot from the official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F40Aj.png)

Please help me with this!

Comment: You decide first where you want the video to be saved. Then you make a File class instance with the full path of the file. After that generate an uri using FileProvider.getUriForFile().

Comment: `The boolean only tells whether the video was successfully saved or not.` Well...?? And was it?